# pushViewController to open a view in landscape

Tags: iphone, landscape, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to open a view in landscape by pushing on navigation controller but it always open in portrait.

First view is in portrait and when I click on a button then next view should be in landscape.

I am trying following code

Calling View:

```
ResultViewController *resultView = [[ResultViewController alloc] init];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:resultView animated:YES];
```

View that should open in landscape:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
        return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Is there something else to try here?

Thanks

Comment: did u got the solution, if yes please post as answer

Comment: No I didn't get the answer. Instead I changed my application design.

Answer (score 0):

Try..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    //return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
    return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft));
}
```

and then...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:YES];

}
```

in resultView

Comment: I have tried that too but it only change the status bar to landscape and my resultView remains in portrait mode. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Is your view a UIViewController, UITabBarController, or UINavigationController?